# passing std::function as a parameter to for_each

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, foreach, lambda

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

std::function<void(int)> sample_function()
{
    return
        [](int x) -> void
    {
        if (x > 5)
            std::cout << x;
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 45, 50 };
    std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), sample_function);
}
```

i'm trying to pass the sample_function() to for_each but i encounter with this error

Error   C2197   'std::function ': too many arguments for call

Comment: This code does not pass `std::function` to `for_each`. It passes `sample_function`, which is a function that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `std::function<void(int)>`. The error message is correct: `sample_function` takes no arguments, so cannot be called with elements of the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

std::function<void(int)> sample_function =  [](int x)
{
    if (x > 5)  std::cout << x << ' ';
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 45, 50 };
    std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), sample_function);
}
```

The output is

```
10 15 20 25 35 45 50
```

Or if you indeed want to define a function that returns an object of type `std::function` then you can write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

std::function<void(int)> sample_function()
{
    return  [](int x)
            {
                if (x > 5)  std::cout << x << ' ';
            };
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 45, 50 };
    std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), sample_function() );
}
```

The output will be the same as shown above. Pay attention to the call

```
    std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), sample_function() );
                                                                ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis to evoke a function call to `sample_function` which in turn it will return `std::function` object for your `for_each`:

```
std::function<void(int)> sample_function() {
  return [](int x) -> void {
     if (x > 5) std::cout << x;
  };
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 45, 50 };
    std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), sample_function());
                                                                 ^^
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7712496e198eb41d)